# Proxy machine to forward SQL Server request onto another SQL Server machine in the Azure cloud

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, proxy

So a current problem is that we inherited many machines that have total of about 500 application exe's. We are physically moving and have realized that someone had not saved source code and there are too many application to identify and re-write.

Issue statement: hundreds of machines are sending request to SQL Server with user `sa` and a `BLANK PASSWORD` :( and for the move we are setting up everything in Azure Cloud. Azure SQL enforces password policy on VM (IaaS) etc..  I want to INTERCEPT and TRANSFORM any application that is trying to connect with  using some type of PROXY layer ..

I was looking at Node Proxy stuff, and SQL server alias etc..  but it seems that what I want to do is this

Proxy Server machine

```
-->  500 incoming SQL Server connections 
--> Server  \\XSQL2
-->  User    "sa"
-->  Password  ""
```

So

```
<add key="conn" value="data source=XSQL2; initial catalog=SomeDB;uid=sa;pwd=" />
```

but then for the Proxy to handle delegating the translation to Azure and sending (replacing) with

```
<add key="conn" value="data source=myclouddbs.westus.cloudapp.azure.com,1433; initial catalog=SomeDB;uid=myUser;pwd=MyPassword123" />
```

Am I making any sense at all?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'm sure we can all agree that blank sa passwords are a terrible, terrible thing, I understand why it can't be changed.

I'm unsure where you've got the information about disallowing a blank sa password in Azure; possibly Azure SQL? Anyway, even if the SQL Azure IaaS VMs have that restriction (I'm not sure they do) you can always install SQL into a blank Windows VM yourself, which won't come with any restrictions. If the App Server can be moved to Azure too, that should work, but if it can't be moved you'll want to set up a VPN to the on-premises system so that the data's secure in transmission - I'm guessing if the original Dev thought a blank sa password was ok, they weren't bothered about encryption in transit...

Comment: No,  the VM with sql server seems to "accept" blank  , then you view the account and it gets set to "disabled"